# Generic solution of 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN' issue

Tags: html, iframe, x-frame-options

I am trying to open `http://teeSpring.com/` in an iframe. It is throwing `Refused to display 'http://teespring.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.` error.

I have gone through multiple answers but none of it worked for me. Most of the solutions are specific to google-maps, facebook or youtube video. 
Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <base target="_blank" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="http://teespring.com" name="frame1" style="border: 0; width:20%; height:20%; overflow:auto;">

        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

I did use `target="_blank"` but no luck.

> > Note: Trying to open third party pages. So I have no control over adding header or other meta data.

Comment: Which server side language are you using?

Comment: None for now. Right now I just have a static page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`teespring.com` is telling your visitors' browsers that they should not display it in a frame.

You have four options:

- Talk to whomever runs `teespring.com` and convince them not to do that
- Just link to them instead of trying to shove them into a frame
- Don't point your visitors to them at all
- Proxy their site and point the iframe at your proxy (this may step into copyright infringement territory)