# I'm trying to embed text in my HTML using this code, but I keep getting this error

Tags: javascript, html, cross-domain

The code:

```
<object type="text/html" data="http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NASDAQ:GOOG">
```

The error:

Refused to display 'http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NASDAQ:GOOG' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as here: [Generic solution of 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN' issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22579412/generic-solution-of-x-frame-options-to-sameorigin-issue)

Google is telling your visitors' browsers that they should not display it in a frame.

You have four options:

Talk to whomever runs Google.com and convince them not to do that
Just link to them instead of trying to shove them into a frame
Don't point your visitors to them at all
Proxy their site and point the iframe at your proxy (this may step into copyright infringement territory)