# Button inside iframe doesn't work

Tags: html, iframe, paypal

The buttons inside the iframe page doesn't work. ( PayPal button that opens a Paypal cart page )

The page with iframe : https://www.keymarket.de/microsoft-access-2010-p-33-checkout.html

The original webpage : https://payivy.com/v/Windows%207%20Professional%20SP1%20Key

The button on the original page works but the one on the iframe page doesn't respond .

Answer (score 1):

When I tried it I got the following error message at the console:

```
Refused to display 'yoururl' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

You can't set `X-Frame-Options` on an iframe. It is a response header set by the domain that you're requesting the resource from, so in your case PayPal.

In this case they have set the header to SAMEORIGIN, which means that they have stopped the loading of their resource in an iframe that is outside of their own domain.

To learn more about `X-Frame-Options` check out this link:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

Also see here:

[Generic solution of 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN' issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22579412/generic-solution-of-x-frame-options-to-sameorigin-issue)

Comment: my intention is to open the link as a new tab . I know about the x-frame option because its a security of paypal . any chance i can make the iframe open the links from the buttons as a new tab ?

Comment: There's a number of things - do you have access to the webpage in order to change the structure of the PayPal link? You could try to load all links on the page in the parent window: <base target="_parent" />

If you do have access to the html let me know and I'll update my answer with more options.

Comment: I dont have access to the PayIvy page as its a gateway. I only have access to the keymarket.de domain to change things .